# What is the use of 'scope' parameter mentioned in HTTP Post Method for OAuth Specification?

Tags: http, token, access-token

I want to generate simple Post Method. I know about client_id and client_secret, However, I don't know about Scope parameter, which is present in the body.
Detailed Picture:[image: Detailed Picture]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5r143L6.png

Comment: ignore image and i want to know the term scope present in body? @melpomene

Comment: @mahen here 'scope' parameter means different syntax for different OAuth Providers like Facebook, Google or LinkedIn ? Which one you asking for? Please specify that also in your query.

Comment: Oh, is this OAuth?

Comment: @melpomene.. yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope Parameter here is **A comma or space separated list of Permissions to request from the person using your app**. It is used in OAuth 2.0 Specification. For example in facebook you can see permission set in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#basic-permissions
[image]

So your example can be like `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
   client_id=123456789
   &redirect_uri=http://example.com/
   &scope=publish_stream,share_item,offline_access,manage_pages`

Answer (score 1):

According to Slack API documentation

> OAuth scopes **let you specify exactly how your app needs to access** a
>   Slack user's account. As an app developer, you specify your desired
>   scopes in the initial OAuth authorization request. **When a user is
>   responding to your OAuth request, the requested scopes will be
>   displayed to them** when they are asked to approve your request

Hope this [link](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes) will be useful to you.